# How to remove affiliation from title

Tags: titles, affiliation, author

I am writing a paper in APA format and am trying to figure out how to get rid of the "Affiliation" that is printed on the title page. This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{sometitle}
\shorttitle{sometitle}
\author{someauthor}
\abstract{asfdasdfasdf}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a dummy `\affiliation` (empty doesn't work, `\mbox{}` does).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{sometitle}
\shorttitle{sometitle}
\author{someauthor}
\affiliation{\mbox{}}

\abstract{asfdasdfasdf}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, avoid `utf8x`: it's unmaintained and does nothing that the current `utf8` option can do. If you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can even be omitted.